# Phonegap plugin result when app is not active anymore

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to edit [the phonegap/cordova PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) plugin for android in order to not create an status-bar Notification when app is not active but always doing some javascript work.

I want to receive my GCM message an do some work on it **with javascript** at anytime.

*GCM message received by PushPlugin => javascript function called.*

I've no problem to make this working when my cordova app is active (ie in foreground or paused).
But I can't use `sendJavascript(...)` when the app has been destroyed. It makes the app crash.

Is there a way to keep the callback context or to wake the webview when the app is not active anymore ?

PS : I'm completely lost within all my google research that give me old results and all different versions of phonegap.

UPDATE :

I've actually that code :

```
public class PushPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

private static CallbackContext callbackCont;


public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
       callbackCont = callbackContext;

       PluginResult progressResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "Start");
       progressResult.setKeepCallback(true);
       callbackCont.sendPluginResult(progressResult);
}


//Fired by an Receiver
public static void action(JSONObject _json) {

        PluginResult progressResult = new     PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "Message");
        progressResult.setKeepCallback(true);
        callbackCont.sendPluginResult(progressResult);
}

}
```

As expected the javascript success function is fired only when app is active (foreground or   paused)

Comment: Is there a reason this is tagged as google-chrome-app?

Comment: Yes it's at first a google chrome package app built with https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps for mobile. I think there is no help coming from that but I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Okay, well mobile-chrome-apps already support `chrome.gcm`(https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/tree/master/chrome-cordova/plugins/chrome.gcm) for Android.  That Push plugin is not maintained by us and is unrelated to mobile-chrome-apps.  You can still try to get it to work for iOS, but will need to file feedback with them (suggest the github repo issue tracker).

Comment: Oh. I've looked at PushPlugin because I get `Permission not supported by cca: gcm (skipping)` from cca.` (I'm going to post an issue on Github)
And, will `chrome.gcm` work when app is not active ?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  Looks like you [filed this issue](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/149) (thanks for that!).  GCM is just the latest addition to our supported api's and `cca` has not been updated on npm yet.  Grab the latest source from our git repo or wait for our next npm publish.

Comment: I've built my own version of cca. It looks like there is a bug with GCM plugin when app is not active. See https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the app is at first a chrome packaged app, build for mobile with cca, I use now the chrome app GCM plugin that is just supported by cca and that wake up the app when an new message is coming.

See https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/tree/master/chrome-cordova/plugins/chrome.gcm