# New GCM mobile-chrome-apps can't compile

Tags: android, google-chrome-app

I'm doing some research in link with this question : [Phonegap plugin result when app is not active anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349847/phonegap-plugin-result-when-app-is-not-active-anymore)

So, I've fork https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps and built my own version according to https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/dev-docs/release-instructions.md in order to use the gcm compatibility with mobile chrome apps that have been added a few days later and that haven't been published yet on npm.

But, when running `cca build` it seems the GCM plugin is not going very well :

```
[javac] Compiling 28 source files to /Users/Guillaume/Documents/Informatique/Web/ChromeApps/EssaiMobile/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
[javac] /Users/Guillaume/Documents/Informatique/Web/ChromeApps/EssaiMobile/platforms/android/src/org/chromium/GcmReceiver.java:9: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
[javac] import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
[javac]                                  ^
[javac] /Users/Guillaume/Documents/Informatique/Web/ChromeApps/EssaiMobile/platforms/android/src/org/chromium/GcmReceiver.java:13: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol: class WakefulBroadcastReceiver
[javac] public class GcmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
[javac]                                  ^
[javac] /Users/Guillaume/Documents/Informatique/Web/ChromeApps/EssaiMobile/platforms/android/src/org/chromium/GcmIntentService.java:52: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method completeWakefulIntent(android.content.Intent)
[javac] location: class org.chromium.GcmReceiver
[javac]         GcmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
[javac]                    ^
[javac] /Users/Guillaume/Documents/Informatique/Web/ChromeApps/EssaiMobile/platforms/android/src/org/chromium/GcmReceiver.java:18: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method startWakefulService(android.content.Context,android.content.Intent)
[javac] location: class org.chromium.GcmReceiver
[javac]         startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
[javac]         ^
[javac] /Users/Guillaume/Documents/Informatique/Web/ChromeApps/EssaiMobile/platforms/android/src/org/chromium/GcmReceiver.java:19: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method setResultCode(int)
[javac] location: class org.chromium.GcmReceiver
[javac]         setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
[javac]         ^
[javac] /Users/Guillaume/Documents/Informatique/Web/ChromeApps/EssaiMobile/platforms/android/src/org/chromium/GcmReceiver.java:14: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[javac]     @Override
[javac]     ^
[javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] 6 errors
```

I'm really not at ease with Java. And I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just add [cordova-plugin-android-support-v4](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-android-support-v4/) plugin to your project and all errors disappears !

`cca plugin add https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-android-support-v4`